# Deutsches Wort für Babykleidungsstück »body«

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request

Wie nennt sich das Kleidungsstück mit langen oder kurzen Ärmeln aber ohne Beine, das sich zwischen den Beinen des Babys zuknöpfen lässt? Babys tragen es als erste Schicht über der Windel.

Es gibt noch den Strampelanzug oder Strampler, der jedoch Beine hat und eher über dem *body* getragen wird.
Ansonsten fiel mir das Wort Leibchen ein, aber damit verbinde ich eher Trikots oder farbige (grellgelbe) Sporthemden als Mannschaftskennzeichnung,: Das Leibchen ist unten offen wie ein normales Oberteil.

Wir haben von anderen Eltern das Wort *body* übernommen, aber gibt es auch ein deutsches Wort?

Leo nennt als Übersetzung für das textile *body* nur »Body«.
Bei Wikipedia steht es unter Body, kurz für »Bodysuit«, Englisch für »Körperanzug«, aber das ist doch kein Wort.

[image]
<sub>(source: [druckdichdrauf.de](https://www.druckdichdrauf.de/out/pictures/master/product/1/babybody.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Das gibt es unter gleichem Namen übrigens auch für Erwachsene, meist Frauen.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ich stell jetzt einfach mal die Behauptung auf:

**Nein**, es gibt kein anderes Wort im Deutschen dafür. Jedenfalls kein gebräuchliches und es wird ähnlich wie die Jeans für alle Kleidungsstücke dieser Art verwendet (und jetzt komme mir bitte niemand mit Nietenhose ;) ).

Allerdings könnte man den Body/Bodysuit noch als

> Einteiler

bezeichnen, doch würde das auch die Strampler mit einschließen.

---

Regionalismen will ich allerdings nicht ausschließen. Immerhin wird das [T-Shirt](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-Shirt), von dem ich sagen würde es gebe auch keine Alternative, anscheinend regional als an das oben angedachte Leibchen/Leiberl/Leible oder Nicki bezeichnet.

Comment: Zustimmung. Die Generation vor mir kannte das Kleidungsstück nicht, da bestand Unterwäsche für Babies aus (Flügel-)Hemden und Höschen. Ständiges Rausrutschen war normal.

Comment: @Stephie Das ist interessant. Ich war davon ausgegangen, dass man das Kleidungsstück schon zu Zeiten benutzte, als englische Wörter noch nicht so häufig waren.

Comment: Meine Kids sind zwar schon eine Weile aus dem Alter (9 und 15 Jahre), aber schon als die klein waren, hießen die Dinger "Body"... deshalb: Full Ack!

Comment: Zur zeitlichen Einordnung: In der Kiste mit Babysachen aus den 70ern, die meine Mutter vom Speicher holte als das erste Enkelkind unterwegs war, fanden sich Strampler und die besagten Teile Unterwäsche, aber keine Bodies.